# Laravel Socialite Gitlab 401

Tags: laravel, authentication, gitlab, guzzle, laravel-socialite

I have a local project where i'd like to use my gitlab credentials to login.
I am using Laravel Socialite for this and downloaded the socialiteproviders/gitlab package into my project.

In gitlab.mycompany.be, I have created an application key, a secret key and the uri are as follows:

```
http://react.test/login
http://react.test/login/gitlab/callback
```

I have included the providers:

```
'gitlab' => [
        'client_id' => env('GITLAB_KEY'),
        'client_secret' => env('GITLAB_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('GITLAB_REDIRECT_URI'),
        'instance_uri' => env('GITLAB_BASE_URL'),
    ],
```

And my LoginController looks like this:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}

public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('gitlab')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('GitLab')->user();
    $accessTokenResponseBody = $user->accessTokenResponseBody;
    // $user->token;
}
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('tasks', "TaskController");

Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/gitlab/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

What my .env looks like:

```
GITLAB_TOKEN=***
GITLAB_KEY=***
GITLAB_SECRET=***
GITLAB_REDIRECT_URI=http://react.test/login/gitlab/callback
GITLAB_BASE_URL=http://gitlab.mycompany.be/
GITLAB_METHOD=token
GITLAB_HOST="http://gitlab.mycompany.be/"
```

I am able to login with my account from gitlab.mycompany.be, but after the redirect I am getting the following message:

> **GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (401)**
>
> **Client error: `POST https://gitlab.com/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client authentication failed due to unknown client, no client authenticat (truncated...)**

Why is guzzle returning a 401 unauthorized ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question for anyone else who might be interested:

I changed:

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('gitlab')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('GitLab')->user();
}
```

To

```
public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('gitlab')->stateless()->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('GitLab')->stateless()->user();
}
```

And then further in my callback I store the user in the DB

```
public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request)
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('gitlab')->stateless()->user();

    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

    Auth::login($authUser, true);

    return redirect()->route('/');
}
```

And now it's working exactly as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the callback URL you provided 
both in gitlab/github / any provider is same with in application (config/services.php)